# ApiExplorer can't determine ApiParameterSource when a POST method has multiple parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST method that, due to a [custom HttpParameterBinding](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API) which is applied to the method, accepts *multiple* parameters. (Without custom bindings, POST methods can only accept 1 parameter.) The problem is that ApiExplorer is unable to determine the ApiParameterSource of these parameters. The source should be `FromBody` but instead is `Unknown`. This only happens when there are multiple parameters. Things work fine if there is only 1 parameter even when using the same parameter binding.

The problem happens in the [ASP.NET Web API Help Page's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/5.2.3) `HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GenerateRequestModelDescription()` method:

```
    private static void GenerateRequestModelDescription(HelpPageApiModel apiModel, ModelDescriptionGenerator modelGenerator, HelpPageSampleGenerator sampleGenerator)
    {
        ApiDescription apiDescription = apiModel.ApiDescription;
        foreach (ApiParameterDescription apiParameter in apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions)
        {
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // In the line below, apiParameter.Source = Unknown, not FromBody
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            if (apiParameter.Source == ApiParameterSource.FromBody)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

(To be clear, the `Source` property is determined by the framework's ApiExplorer class, not in the Help Page area.)

My API method has the custom HttpParameterBinding applied to it as follows, and the parameters are explicitly tagged as `FromBody`:

```
[HttpPost, SimplePostVariableParameterBinding]
public SomeObject GetSomeObject([FromBody]Object2 obj2, [FromBody]Object3 obj3) {
    ...
}
```

I also tried setting the parameter binding's `WillReadBody` property to true in case that has an effect but unfortunately it did not. (And it broke my custom binding so I undid the change.)

I'm trying to understand what is going on, or to simply better understand how ApiExplorer determines the source value. In the meantime I have hacked the Help Page's class to work around this problem but I'd like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take multi parameters in your method, you have to pass data via query string. Otherwise you can use the following way:

```
[HttpPost]
public SomeObject GetSomeObject([FromBody] dynamic postData) {
    ...
}
```

In method's body, you are able to get post data as follows: postData.[parameter name]